# Android Room persistence SQLiteConstraintException when inserting items twice

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I have been working with the Room persistence library which worked great until I items in two different insertions.

**Sound Entity class**

```
@Entity
public class Sound {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int sid;
@ColumnInfo(name = "sound_theme")
private int soundTheme;
@ColumnInfo(name = "sound_name")
private String soundName;
@ColumnInfo(name = "sound_resource")
private int soundResource;
@ColumnInfo(name = "sound_image_resource")
private int soundImageResource;
@ColumnInfo(name = "sound_favorite")
private boolean isFavorite;
@ColumnInfo
private int usedCount;
@ColumnInfo
private long lastUsed;


 public Sound(int soundTheme, String soundName, int soundResource, int soundImageResource, boolean isFavorite, int usedCount, long lastUsed) {
    this.soundTheme = soundTheme;
    this.soundName = soundName;
    this.soundResource = soundResource;
    this.soundImageResource = soundImageResource;
    this.isFavorite = isFavorite;
    this.usedCount = usedCount;
    this.lastUsed = lastUsed;
}
```

Watch that I have a sound id as a primary key which auto-generates.

**Sound DAO**

```
@Dao
public interface SoundDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM sound")
List<Sound> getAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM sound WHERE sid IN (:soundIds)")
List<Sound> loadAllByIds(int[] soundIds);

@Query("SELECT * FROM sound WHERE sound_name LIKE :name LIMIT 1")
Sound findByName(String name);

@Query("SELECT * FROM sound WHERE sid LIKE :id LIMIT 1")
Sound findById(int id);

@Insert
void insertAll(Sound... sounds);

@Insert
void insertAllArrList(ArrayList<Sound> sounds);

@Delete
void delete(Sound sound);

@Query("DELETE FROM sound")
public void deleteAllSounds();
}
```

The error goes with this line:

```
      if (focusedSound.isFavorite()) 
      favorites.soundDao().insertAll(focusedSound); 
      else favorites.soundDao().delete(selectedSound);
```

first insertion goes well(If you insert multiple items in this it will also work), second time you insert it crashes.
I assume it has something to do with the primary key for the sound id(sid) but I am not sure how to solve it.

here are some of the error logs:

```
06-03 20:03:36.454 8807-8807/com.zaid.green.soundpress E/InputEventReceiver: 
Exception dispatching input event.
06-03 20:03:36.454 8807-8807/com.zaid.green.soundpress E/MessageQueue-JNI: 
Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-03 20:03:36.460 8807-8807/com.zaid.green.soundpress E/MessageQueue-JNI: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: 
Sound.sid (code 1555)
SQLiteConnection at nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)  
SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
    at
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the issue is with the primary constraint and duplicate items being insertion.

Solution : define [`OnConflictStratergy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/OnConflictStrategy) on your `@intert` methods as

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAll(Sound... sounds);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAllArrList(ArrayList<Sound> sounds);
```

As you can see, this will replace the new objects with old ones

Comment: It does fix the problem, do you think it is the programmatically way to treat this?  or it may cause me some problems further in the development

Comment: I have just continued a bit, it did solve the problem but the new problems are when I want to delete the favorite item after inserting more than one item it crashed for trying to remove an item with a null id. is there a way to handle it? because I fill the solution only solves some of the case

Comment: hmm, are you using the new object (while deletion) that we just used to replace the old one, because with this solutions, the old id or object doesn't exists any more

Comment: Link to documentation should be https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/OnConflictStrategy